# SQL Removing Duplicates in Combinations

Tags: sql

How can I make sure that the output of a SQL query produces unique tuple values (disregarding order). For example, if I have the output (1,2) I do not want (2,1) to appear.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing a self join.  In that case don't use <> use > on the ID.  Example `SELECT T1.*, T2.* from table A INNER JOIN Table B on A.Text = B.Text and A.ID < B.ID`  Regardless, the SQL is going to be necessary to help specifically. No true answer can be provided as the Question is too vague.

Comment: Please show the SQL query that is generated the results with duplicates.

Comment: And in never hurts to know what RDBSM are you talking about. @SagarJoon Distinct will not help.

Comment: I would argue that in the RDBMS world, in general, we deal with ordered tuples, so (1,2) is not the same as (2,1). This type of thing can become very challenging with more than a couple of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS, but the following is standard (ANSI) SQL:

```
select distinct least(col_1, col_2), greatest(col_1, col_2)
from the_table;
```